# How to construct regex for password in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, passwords

I'm creating a new stored procedure for user register on my web application. I need to validate user password to be in a format of:

- It must contain at least one number or letter
- It must contain at least one special character
  I need to manage to write this using regex.

This is for a new Database that i have created in SQL server 2017. My database is okay working fine and also my email validation is fine and working.

```
IF (@password NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%' OR @password NOT LIKE '%~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:"|\;,./<>?''%' OR LEN(@password) < 8)
        BEGIN
                SET @message = 'Invalid credentials'
                RETURN;
        END
                ELSE
                SET @message = 'Success'
                RETURN;
                END
```

this is my code so far ad honestly i tried a lot of combinations and still nothing.

I expect the output for a password like !Password123 to be `Success` but instead i'm still getting "`Invalid credentials`" and for password like Password123! i am still getting "`Invalid credentials`"

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support REGEX. It has some REGEX *LIKE* functionality. This is able to do be done in the DB, in a long way, but would be best done on the application side.

Comment: If you're trying to validate a password in the RDBMS then your passing it as plain text to the RDBMS; and therefore creating a huge security risk. Before the password get's anywhere near the database it should already be salted and hashed. Passing a plain text password to the RDBMS will allow anyone that can perform a trace or use extended events to intercept those values. Not even a `sysadmin` should be able to find out what the password is of a user.

Comment: Actually you can use REGEX in SQL Server if you write a CLR proc.  But I agree with Larnu that the database is not the place to check business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be ideal to have access to a full regex engine, which would let you write a more robust password check, you actually can handle your requirements using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator.  The problem I see with your current code is that you are not escaping the square brackets in the second `LIKE` expression which checks for the presence of a special character.  You may tell SQL Server how you plan to escape square brackets using `ESCAPE` as follows:

```
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(500);
SET @password = '!Password123';

SELECT 1
WHERE
    @password NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%' OR
    @password NOT LIKE '%[~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}\[\]:"|\;,./<>?'']%' ESCAPE '\' OR
    LEN(@password) < 8;
```

The above query returns nothing, indicating that `!Password123` is a valid password.

Comment: Thank you very much that was the problem. I was not escaping the square brackets and that's why it wasn't working. Thank you very much now everything is fine.